# Queue<T>.Dequeue returns null

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a scenario where

- multiple threads are pushing data on a Queue
- only ONE thread is processing data using code below

code -

```
  while ( Continue )
  {
        while ( queue.Count > 0 )
        {
             MyObj o = queue.Dequeue();
             someProcess(o);
        }
        myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
  }
```

But sometimes, queue.Dequeue() returns null in the scenario above
What gives ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/16/a-more-usable-thread-safe-collection.aspx).

Also, here's a very minimal skeleton of a "channel" for communication between threads:

```
public class Channel<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (_queue)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
            if (_queue.Count == 1)
                Monitor.PulseAll(_queue);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        lock (_queue)
        {
            while (_queue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(_queue);

            return _queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting but i'd prefer to use locking minimally, perhaps time to finally go through the powerthreading library in detail

Comment: If you want to use a standard container from multiple threads, the above code is minimal! But powerthreading is worth a look anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You need to synchronise the access to the queue. Put `lock` statements around all code sections that access the queue (both reading and writing). If you access the queue simultaneously from multiple threads the internal structures may be corrupted and just about anything can happen.

Comment: if "access" means reading, there's only 1 reader
rest(2) are writers

Comment: @Kumar: Having two writers (on separate threads) add to a collection that's not inherently thread-safe is going to cause issues. Guffa's right; you need to synchronize access. See my answer for a sort of casual explanation.

Comment: Hmm... would you be able to use a `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue` instead of lock statements?  I haven't dealt with this class yet.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4, you can avoid locking by using the ConcurrentQueue type: http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/02/04/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue.aspx

Comment: Note that in this scenario an exclusive lock makes sense. If the scenario were many readers, one writer, instead of the opposite, then a ReaderWriterLockSlim would be a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

You say:

> multiple threads are pushing data on a Queue

The `Queue<T>.Enqueue` method is not thread-safe. This means that work gets done **within** the `Enqueue` method that needs to be synchronized if multiple threads are calling it. A simple example would be updating the `Count` property. It's a safe bet that somewhere in the `Enqueue` method there's a line that looks something like this:

```
++count;
```

But as we all know, this isn't an atomic operation. It's really more like this (in terms of what's actually *happening*):

```
int newCount = count + 1;
count = newCount;
```

So say the `count` is currently 5, and Thread 1 gets past `int newCount = count + 1`... then Thread 1 thinks, "OK, the count is now 5, so I'll make it 6." But the very next operation that gets executed is where Thread 2 gets to `int newCount = count + 1` and thinks the same thing as Thread 1 ("the count is now 6"). So two items have just been added to the queue, but the count only went from 5 to 6.

This is just a very basic example of how a non thread-safe method like `Queue<T>.Enqueue` can get messed up when access is not synchronized. It doesn't specifically explain what's happening in your question; my intention is simply to point out that **what you're doing is not thread-safe and will cause unexpected behavior**.

Answer (score 6):

Guffa is correct, having multiple threads reading and writing to the queue will cause problems, because Queue<T> is not thread safe.

If you're on .NET 4, use the [ConcurrentQueue<T>](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/02/04/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue.aspx) class, which is thread safe. If you're not on .NET 3 or earlier, you can either do your own locking, as Guffa pointed out, or use a 3rd party library.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue<T> looks very good, any port of that class in .net 3.5 world ?

Comment: Yes, there is a port from Microsoft. It's inside the RX framework for .NET 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make sure nothing's pushing `null` values into the queue.  `null`s are allowed as queued values.  Also, according to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), only `Queue<T>`'s static members are thread-safe, so beware of doing reading and writing across threads.

Comment: You're misunderstanding that document.  It's saying that only the static _members_ of `Queue` are guaranteed to be thread-safe.  Assigning a Queue to a static variable does not magically make it thread-safe.

Comment: there are no nulls being pushed in

Comment: Following up on SLaks' comment: `Queue<T>` does not have any static members. That bit of the documentation is irrelevant boilerplate (for the current version of the class, at least - the versions in the 2.0 and 3.0 frameworks each had one static method, `ReferenceEquals`).

Comment: Thanks, @SLaks and @Jeff.  That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you solve the problem that way?

```
while (IsRunning)
{
    do
    {
        MyObj myObj = queue.Dequeue();
        if (myObj != null)
        {
            DoSomethingWith(myObj);
        }
    } while (myObj != null);

    myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

#### Update

Ok, after reading Earwickers comment and all the other answers, you are all right and i'm just false. So **please don't use the code above in multithreaded contexts** .

Comment: Because the `Dequeue` method of `Queue` isn't thread safe. If a reader is trying to do this at the same time as a writer is trying to insert something, the results will be... unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using non-generic Queue (not that I advise to use it), you can use Queue.Synchronized method to get a thread-safe wrapper:

```
Queue queue = Queue.Synchronized(new Queue());
```

Otherwise you should take care of locking yourself, as others suggest.